# nginx rewrite secure link

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite a secure link, here is my nginx conf:

```
    location /files/ {
        deny all;
        return 403;
    }

    # MEMBERS ONLY #####
    location /auth/ {
        secure_link $arg_h,$arg_e;
        secure_link_md5 authkey$uri$arg_e;
        if ($secure_link = "") {
            return 403;
        }
        if ($secure_link = "0") {
            return 403;
        }
        rewrite  ^/auth/(.*)$  /files/$1  break;
        add_header Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=$arg_f";
    }
```

Its work if I put download link like this:

```
http://13.37.13.37/auth/path/to/dir/file.zip?h=sdiouqosid&e=1337&f=the_file.zip
```

but it does not if I print link like this:

```
http://subdir.mysite.org/auth/path/to/dir/file.zip?h=sdiouqosid&e=1337&f=the_file.zip
```

Please note:

- subdir.mysite.org has "A" redir to 13.37.13.37 in DNS records
- 13.37.13.37 is different server than mysite.org

Also:
- http://subdir.mysite.org/path/to/something/somefile.zip works great, it's only when I use secure_link that it fails (returns either a 403 or a fail to load ressource). I guess it has something to do with my url_rewrite. I tried a lot of things without any success regarding this weird behaviour.
Thank you for your help

EDIT:
full nginx below:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  2;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush      on;
    tcp_nodelay     on;
    #server_tokens off;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=freeuser:10m;

    map $request_uri $request_qs {
        default '';
        ~.*\?(?P<key>.+)$ $key;
    }

    server {

        listen          80;
        server_name     localhost;
        root            /var/www;


        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            access_log off;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
        }


        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|swf|mp3)$ {
            expires        365d;
            access_log     off;
        }


        location /file/ {
            deny all;
            return 403;
           }


        location /auth/ {
            secure_link $arg_h,$arg_e;
            secure_link_md5 authkey$uri$arg_e$remote_addr;
            if ($secure_link = "") {
                return 403;
            }
            if ($secure_link = "0") {
                return 403;
            }
            rewrite  ^/auth/(.*)$  /file/$1  break;
            add_header Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=$arg_f";
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: could you paste the rest of the conf, at least the rest of the server block.

Comment: I edited first post with full conf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem editing the "Reverse" (hostname).
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I'd say change the `/files` block, because right now it's logical to return 403, because you just deny all.

```
location /files/ {
    internal;
}
```

This would return 404 for non authorized instead of 403, don't know if that works for you.

Comment: if I change like you said, anyone unauthorized would be able to download protected files (implying they guess the path). Also it works fine already that way. It only fails if I put "subdir.mysite.org" instead of the "server ip". The problem seems to be 'if ($secure_link = "")' that goes 'true' if I set domain name instead of ip...

Comment: `internal` means that no one can access the `files` directory from outside the server, which means only server rewrites are able to access that folder.
which leaves only the `rewrite  ^/auth/(.*)$  /files/$1  break;` rewrite to access it.
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#internal

Comment: Ok. This does not solve the problem anyway, since the behaviour of the script goes as expected when i put the server ip, but fails when i put the subdomain. thanks for trying...